# Windows Phone - Graphical corruption after upgrading from SDK 7.1 to 7.1.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1.1

I am writing an XNA game for Windows Phone. I recently upgraded my Windows Phone SDK from version 7.1 to 7.1.1. You can read about the details of the SDK patches [here](http://developer.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk), but this is the summary:

> Windows Phone SDK 7.1.1 Update offers developers tools and options to
>   help them develop and test applications for 256-MB Windows Phone
>   devices.

After performing the upgrade my game now renders with major graphical corruption when running in the Windows Phone **Emulator**.

Here is what it looked like before and after:

[image: Game running on 7.1]

[image: Game running on 7.1.1]

On actual hardware, it runs fine.

I have also tested this with the most basic sample apps, and the same issue occurs.

- Rolling back to version 7.1 of the SDK **does** fix the issue.
- Re-installing version 7.1.1 of the SDK **does not** fix the issue.
- Updated my computers drivers **does not** fix the issue.
- Upgrading to version 7.8 of the SDK **does not** fix the issue.

I am not able to upgrade to version 8.0 of the SDK because that is Windows 8 PC only (which I don't have).

I am at a loss as to what else I can try. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like you're hitting a bug with newer drivers in the newer emulator and that there isn't much to do it (especially if reinstalling doesn't help)